# SQLite issue on Jelly Bean

Tags: android

I've an application which records few attributes of a foreground activity. I've used local DB to store the data and when user requests for display, I fetch the data from this DB and display it on a list view. Its working fine with GB,ICS. But the database transaction is very irregular in JellyBean. Empty is getting returned. I'm unable to know the reason for this. I've tested this with Samsung young, HTC, Sony Ericson Xperia and Samsung S3. The issue is with S3 where its been updated to JB. The following is the logCat trace. please help.

```
try {
        db.open();
        Cursor cursor = db.getStartTime(lastAppName); ;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            DiffStart = cursor.getString(0);
            DiffBright = cursor.getString(1);
            Log.d("wifiRun","brightness: " +DiffBright);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
           }
           SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                        "HH:mm:ss");
            try {
               Date startTime = dateFormat.parse(DiffStart);
               Date endTime = dateFormat.parse(EndingTime);
               diff = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;
               Difference = String.valueOf(diff);
           try {
               double brightnessDouble = Double.parseDouble(DiffBright);
               Log.d("wifiRun","brightnessDouble: " +brightnessDouble);
               //Do my energy calculation.
               } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                npe.printStackTrace();
            }

                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                npe.printStackTrace();
                            }



                            db.update(lastAppName, EndingTime, Difference, AppEnergy);

Cursor cur = db.Select(lastAppName);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                    do {
                                    testBright = cursor.getString(0);
Log.d("wifiRun","testBright: " +testBright);
                                    testEnergy = cursor.getString(1);
                                    Log.d("wifiRun","testEnergy: " +testEnergy);
                                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                                }
       db.close();
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
      sql.printStackTrace();
    }
```

LogCat is as follows:

```
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: 171
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: null
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: null
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: 171
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: 171
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: 171
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: 171
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: 171
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: 171
06-11 12:57:31.258: D/wifiRun(32469): brightness: 171
06-11 12:57:31.263: D/wifiRun(32469): brightnessDouble: 171.0
06-11 12:57:31.263: D/wifiRun(32469): AppEnergy: 13.977
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: null
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: 171
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: null
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: null
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: null
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: null
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: 313.776
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: 171
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: 313.776
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: 171
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: 2.795
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: 171
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: 36.339
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: 171
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: 6.289
06-11 12:57:31.268: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: 171
06-11 12:57:31.273: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: 0.699
06-11 12:57:31.273: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: 171
06-11 12:57:31.273: D/wifiRun(32469): testEnergy: 13.977
06-11 12:57:31.273: D/wifiRun(32469): testBright: 171
```

Comment: put your logcat trace here.

Comment: I've put it. As u can see, its been null many times. Its d log cat ran for just 2 secs. If u run my app for abt a minute, many nulls will appear.

Comment: Show your code to start

Comment: ohhkk..put your code..

Comment: Here's the sample of my code. This code is working in GB, ICS.

Comment: Can you format your code properly and separate your logs from your code block.

Comment: @Arman: I've formatted it. After updating the db with endTime, difference and energy, I'm retrieving brightness value and energy value to see what has got inserted. U can observe in the LogCat that few times, its showing null.

Comment: Format the code block, your try and catch groups are quiet messy. It would be better to align them properly so that we can easily help you in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this things in a different manner which is so common also.

Just create all your database stuffs in a separate class and add all type of methods there.
And for getting data from the table, you may do like below:

```
  // put all column names in a string array
  String[] columns = new String[] { ROW_ID, ROW_NAME };

  // create the cursor
  Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(your_table_name, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
  String result = "";
  //fetch the column indexes through the column name..
  int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(ROW_ID);
  int iName= c.getColumnIndex(ROW_NAME);

  //move the cursor from start to after last one by one and put the data in ur string..
  for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result += c.getString(iRow) + "\n" + c.getString(iName) + "\n";

  // at last return the result for using in your activity..
  return result;
```

It's very easy and hope it will safe you from bugs which are you facing now.